# Does the program check boolean conditions after && if the first one is false?

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-statements

```
if (foo() && bar())
```

Does the program still execute `bar()` even if `foo()` is false? Or is it a better idea to write

```
if (foo())
    if (bar())
```

to avoid `bar()` from being called, if it is a heavy function, for example?

Comment: The right operand is not evaluated if the left operand is evaluated to false.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the duplicate. Didn't know with what wording I'd find that question